# Ruby instance variables nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to measure the amount of time spent on a page. I am trying to store the opening and closing times in instance variable of the controller; however, they either don't initialize or are nil. Here is my code:

```
def table
    @numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
    if @time_opened.nil?
        @time_opened = 1
        @open_time = 0.0
        @close_time = 0.0
    else
        @time_opened += 1
    end

    if @open_time > 0.0
        @close_time = Time.now
    end

    @visit = Visit.new({number: @number, time_spent: @close_time - @open_time})
    @visit.save
end

def show
    url = request.url
    @number = url[url.rindex('/')+1..-1]
    @title = @number

    @open_time = Time.now
end
```

Show is called every time the page who's time I want to measure is displayed. When I check the visit data, number is nil and time_spent is 0.0.

Comment: Where are you setting @time_opened?  I don't think this is the best approach for what you are trying to accomplish but I don't think you are ever setting a value for @time_opened

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't share state across requests using instance variables. Your controller instance is completely destroyed at the end of each request, and a new instance of your controller is created the next time a request is routed to one of its actions.

If you want to persist data, you need to either use [`session`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session) or send the data to the client and persist it via `<input type="hidden">` fields, so it can be sent back with the subsequent request.

Comment: You could also use class variables. These are kept between requests but are still not shared between different application server processes. A more common solution is to use a logging system or at least add/update a database record on each visit.

Comment: @HolgerJust You *could*, but you absolutely shouldn't, so it's really not worth mentioning.